# Saving categorical variable treatment plan in R

Tags: r

The R package `vtreat` provides a handy way of creating "one-hot encoders" for the categorical variables (see a relevant post at the [Win-Vector blog](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/04/encoding-categorical-variables-one-hot-and-beyond/)). Is there any way to save the *treatment plan* `tplan` object for further use (e.g., equivalent mechanism of `pickle` in Python).

```
tplan <- vtreat::designTreatmentsZ(dTrain, vars)
oneHotEncoded <- as.matrix(vtreat::prepare(tplan, dTrain, varRestriction = vars))
```

I would like to transform whatever data I will get with this particular treatment plan (which was computed on the `dTrain`), in a situation where the `dTrain` is no longer available. That is, I cannot re-use `dTrain` the next time I will call the script.

P.s. the solution should not necessary be confined to using `vtreat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R provides the general functions `save()` and `load()` for such purposes.

Here is a reproducible example using code snippets from the post you have linked to:

```
library(titanic)
library(vtreat)

data(titanic_train)

outcome <- 'Survived'
target <- 1
shouldBeCategorical <- c('PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Parch')
for(v in shouldBeCategorical) {
  titanic_train[[v]] <- as.factor(titanic_train[[v]])
}
tooDetailed <- c("Ticket", "Cabin", "Name", "PassengerId")
vars <- setdiff(colnames(titanic_train), c(outcome, tooDetailed))


dTrain <- titanic_train

set.seed(4623762)
tplan <- vtreat::designTreatmentsZ(dTrain, vars, 
                                   minFraction= 0,
                                   verbose=FALSE)


save(tplan, file='tplan.RData')
```

The file `tplan.RData` will be saved in your current working directory; afterwards, in a new R session, when you ask for

```
load('tplan.RData')
```

you will get your `tplan` variable back.

Alternatively, base R functions `saveRDS` and `loadRDS` will also do the job; their usage is exactly similar, and they [seem to be preferable](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/).